# Unable to run typesafe activator UI behind proxy

Tags: akka, typesafe

I'm trying to setup typesafe activator UI under windows.

When I run it for the first time I'm getting this error:

C:\sandbox\typesafe-activator-1.3.6>activator
Getting org.fusesource.jansi jansi 1.11 ...
You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not we
ll configured.

As per the activator Readme I created activatorconfig.txt under C:\Users\.activator\activatorconfig.txt and added there the proxy configuration but when I run the activator again I'm still getting the same error message as if nothing changed.

Any ideas?